# Advice needed on table architecture for storing information about external integration in a Ruby on Rails API application with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

How can I design a database for storing custom integrations for each client in an application where different clients can have integrations with different services (e.g. ATS, HRIS), the catch is Client Alpha can have integration with ATS service X where as client Beta can have integration with service HRIS Y or ATS Z.? I have a single database with a company_id in most of the tables.

Looking for a solution to manage the integration information efficiently. I really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on how I can store the integration information for each client. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a many-to-many (M:M) relationship Clients and Services. This typically results in 3 tables:

- `clients`: information about the individual client.
- `services`: information about each service offered.
- `client_services`: a resolution table having clients and their selected services and any attribute(s) requiring the combination.

It also permits, but does not require, multiple clients to have the same service.

[Demo here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/BzdDDcFp)

Comment: That's good. Sorry I go not know RAILS so cannot give a complete answer.